# Styling background of ghost button : performance

Tags: css, performance

I have a regular button in my layout. Its hover state is making it a ghost button (border and font keeps the color of non-hover state's background and hover background goes transparent).

While I cannot depend on default state of background - transparent - because i need to override the value of non-hover state, what is more efficient performance-wise :

specifically write `background-color: transparent;` or set the color of the background `background-color: #5f5974;` ?

Comment: "While I cannot depend on default state of background - transparent - because i need to override the value of non-hover state" What is that supposed to mean? Whichever state you override the value in doesn't change the fact that the initial value of background-color is transparent.

Comment: Yes you re right, that intial value is transparent at any point, but i simply cannot force it. I mean, let's say the background of the whole page is purple, button has white border of 1 px, white background and purple text.

The hover state keeps the border, so i dont need to write that rule, text needs to be white now so that I do have to write and the background needs to be transparent (or purple - thats the question - what is better performance-wise) but i need to write the rule, because the inital state is overwritten by white color from non-hover state.

Comment: The browser already applies background-color: transparent to every other element that doesn't have some other color defined. You really think it's going to make a huge difference if you set it on just one element at each moment a user hovers over it?